# Если try бросает исключение и после этого в finally бросает исключение, то какое будет выброшено?

Tags: java

Если `try` бросает исключение и после этого в `finally` будет исключение, то какое будет выброшено?

Comment: А что мешает проверить? Это пять строк написать. А вообще будет то, что в finally

Answer (score 4):

```java
 try{
           throw new IllegalStateException("Try exc");
       }
       catch(IllegalStateException e){
           System.out.println("Try exc");
       }
       finally{
           throw new IllegalStateException("Try finn");
       }
```

**Результат:**

Try exc

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Try finn
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:10)
Command exited with non-zero status 1

**Вывод:**

- try- бросает исключение
- catch - его ловит
- finally(будет точно выполнен в независимости) - бросает исключение, исключение пробрасывается наверх

Если без catch

```java
try{
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Try exc");
       }
       finally{
           throw new IllegalStateException("Try finn");
       }
```

**Результат:**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Try finn
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:7)
Command exited with non-zero status 1

**Вывод:**
finally